# Default specification of a C++ vector of pairs of strings as function parameter invalid on gcc-4.1.2?

Tags: c++, initialization, stdvector, default-constructor, std-pair

This builds fine as a parameter to a function declaration on x64 VS100 (MSVC++ 2010) but fails on RHEL5 (gcc 4.1.2):

```
const std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string> >& = std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string> >()
```

The whole function since some have asked is (with said parameter being the 3rd):

```
    bool func(const std::string&, const std::vector<int>&, const std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string> >& = 
        std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string> >(), const std::vector<std::string>& = std::vector<std::string>(), 
        const std::vector<std::string>& = std::vector<std::string>(), const std::vector<double>& = std::vector<double>(), 
        const std::vector<double>& = std::vector<double>(), const std::vector<double>& = std::vector<double>(), 
        const std::vector<double>& = std::vector<double>(), const std::vector<double>& = std::vector<double>(), 
        const std::string& = "", const std::string& = "", const std::string& = "") const;
```

The error I got on RHEL5 gcc-4.1.2 is:

```
line #: error: expected ',' or '...' before '>' token
line #: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)
line #: error: template argument 1 is invalid
line #: error: template argument 2 is invalid
```

Note that this compiles fine on both platforms with 3rd parameter replaced by:

```
std::vector<std::string>& = std::vector<std::string>()
```

My current workaround is to use the latter form and change my implementation a bit to account for it, and this does the job currently. But any ideas why the original usage is failing to build on RHEL5 gcc-4.1.2 and what would be correct usage is very appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It would be *brilliant* if you included the error message that you get with GCC and some compilable code... you want people to spend their time helping you - help them by investing some time in writing the question.

Comment: @us2012: I guess this is supposed to be a parameter (not argument) in a function declaration, with a default value. But yes, it would be helpful to see compilable code, and the error message.

Comment: @us2012 I understood that this is a parameter of a function in the declaration... So no need of name or semicolon... +1 for the error message.

Comment: Ouch, there I go criticising others and then it turns out I missed the "argument" part. Embarrassing. My other comment still stands though.

Comment: @PierreFourgeaud:  As a function parameter, it won't need a semicolon, but it will still need a variable name to set the default value.

Comment: @ZacHowland: No it wouldn't.

Comment: This is accepted as a function parameter by a reasonably up-to-date version of GCC: http://ideone.com/SVrfXM. Unfortunately, I don't have your ancient compiler to test with. What error message do you get?

Comment: apologies: I've put up the error message (all show up at the line where the argument is in the function declaration)

Comment: Oops, I stand corrected.

Comment: We're starting to get somewhere close to an answerable question now. Perhaps you could (a) reduce the function to a *minimal* example that compiles on MSVC but not GCC, and (b) post a *complete* (but still *minimal*) source file (including `#include`s) so we can see if there are any problems elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is correct. What you have is most probably a bug in GCC 4.1. Non-ancient versions of GCC compile this code just fine.

Other than that, make sure you actually include the headers you need:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <utility> // for std::pair
```

Comment: Have you tested on a more recent gcc? Does it compile for you? Please confirm.

Comment: @squashed.bugaboo It compiles on GCC 4.6.4, 4.7.3, 4.8.1. It also compiles on Clang 3.3 and Intel C++ 13.1.3. I have all of those installed. You can also test on various compilers yourself on http://ideone.com.

Comment: Thanks..appreciate this info. I have included all those includes. Still error on gcc-4.1.2; I guess I need to rework this is a vector of strings instead and adjust my implementation.

Comment: @squashed.bugaboo Does it work if you provide a name for the argument? (And then simply ignore it.)

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you haven't included `<vector>`.

On one compiler, it is indirectly included by some other header, so the declaration compiles.

On the other, it has only seen a declaration of `std::vector`, specifying two template parameters, and not the full definition, specifying the default value for the second; so the compiler complains that there should be a second one.

Make sure you're including that, and also `<string>` and `<utility>` for `std::string` and `std::pair`.

Comment: I have included <vector>, <utility>, and <string>; still error on gcc-4.1.2

Comment: OK, it's something else then - either a compiler bug, or a problem with the code you didn't show us. Perhaps you could post a complete example that compiles on MSVC, so we don't have to guess what you're doing?

Comment: Its a very simple function func(...) with this thing as argument inside in a class header, same code on Windows (svn code base) compiles fine. No issues.

Comment: @squashed.bugaboo: So why don't you post that simple function, along with all the headers etc. that make it compile, so we don't have to guess what might be wrong with it?

Comment: I don't see how putting up the whole function which is quite verbose with many arguments, clarifies the issue any more. But I've put it up anyway.

Comment: @squashed.bugaboo: By posting a *minimal complete* example (i.e. a *complete* source file containing a *simple* function definition that compiles on MSVC and not on GCC), we can see whether we can reproduce the problem, and see if there's anything wrong with your code. If we have to tease the necessary information out of you one piece at a time, then the question becomes a pain to answer.

Comment: Thanks..I'll try and post a minimal example later in the evening or tomorrow; but I'm certain there are no issues with the implementation (source) - it is rigorously tested. Also showed in my edited post the workaround that works. For now, I'll go with that, but will post the minimal/complete example later. Thanks again.